# Kernel Panic on Rasp 3B+ preventing boot (tried multiple SD cards, new power supplies, etc)

Tags: boot-issues

A friend gave me his Raspberry Pi 3B+ because it had stopped working.

Hooking it up to HDMI shows the Rainbow Square, and then gives a tons of scrolling text which ends with a kernel panic.

I've tried various different SD cards and different power supplies. Currently, I have it hooked up to my bench supply set at 5V and 2A, powered over GPIO pins (Pin 2 = 5V and Pin 6 = GND). If I turn down the amperage, it `bootloops` after displaying the rainbow square, so I think it's getting enough.

The red LED is solid. The green LED blinks.

I've tried taking out the SD and plugging in a portable USB with a Raspberry image on it, and then there is no green LED at all.

Some images of the boot (these are two separate boots; I'm not sure why there's different outcomes).

[image]

[image]

Edit:

- I used the Raspberry Pi Imager app to load Raspberry Pi OS, Lite, 32 bit/Legacy, 64 bit, Ubuntu, Octopi, FullPageOS, "Bootloader" -> SD Card boot & then USB Boot.
- Did not use a "new" SD card. But I used 4 different known working SD cards (two from other working Pis, two from cameras). I used a USB thumb drive. I used an SSD. All loaded w/ Rasp Pi Imager.
- *My specific question is: can this be fixed? Any further troubleshooting tips?*

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: `I've tried various different SD cards` ... what's on them?

Comment: "I've tried various different SD cards" What OS? How did you install? Did you use NEW SD Card?

Comment: @Milliways & jsotola, I've edited the question to answer your questions.

Comment: You claim to have installed 8 OS! Who knows what you are doing? Try asking ONE question

Comment: @Milliways I don’t understand why you’re confused. I tried one OS, didn’t work, tried another, etc. I was hoping to find one that did. None of them would boot. I am simply trying to get the pi to BOOT into *any* OS.

Comment: Shotgun debugging rarely works and it is impossible to help. I suggest you try a systematic debugging approach and post some meaningful diagnostics. Generally a SD that works on one Pi should work. If the original owner discarded the Pi it is probably because it is damaged.

Comment: That’s fair. I believe it to be hardware. I was hoping someone would see the attached photos and say “oh that often happens when cuz component stops working, do this”, but obviously I was mistaken.